# AngularJS: Using ViewModel-Variables in Callback of Directive-Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm trying to build a directive with a controller, which updates a ViewModel-variable and calls a callback-function. In the callback-function the updated variable should be used, but it still got the old value.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    Var: {{vm.var}}
    <ng-element var="vm.var" func="vm.func()"></ng-element>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.vm = {
        var: 'One',
        func: function() {
            alert($scope.vm.var);
        }
    };
});

app.directive('ngElement', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        bindToController: {
            var: '=',
            func: '&'
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        replace: true,
        template:   '<button ng-click="ctrl.doIt()">Do it</button>',
        controller: function() {
            this.doIt = function() {
                this.var = 'Two';
                this.func();
            };
        }
    };
});
```

So when clicking the button, **doIt()** ist called, updates **var** and calls **func()**. But when **func()** is executed, **var** still got the old value "One". Right after the execution the ViewModel gets updated and the value is "Two".

Is there any way to update the ViewModel before executing the function?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmu6pcv8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your directive is doing, as I've never used bindToController, but this seemed to work:

```
directive('ngElement', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            var: '=',
            func: '&'
        },
        replace: true,
        template:   '<button ng-click="doIt()">Do it</button>',
        controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
            $scope.doIt = function() {
                $scope.var = 'Two';
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.func();
                });
            };
        }]
    };
});
```